# SDL rect not appearing

Tags: c++, sdl, rect

I am trying to get an SDL_Rect to appear on screen with a texture from a bitmap. I run this program and the screen is simply white, with no image.

```
#include "SDL.h"

int main(int argc, char** args) {

    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);

    SDL_Window* window = NULL;
    
    window = SDL_CreateWindow("window", SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, 1280, 720, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);

    SDL_Renderer* renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, 0);

    SDL_Surface* surface = SDL_LoadBMP("car.bmp");

    SDL_Texture* texture = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(renderer, surface);

    SDL_Rect rect;

    rect.x = 0;
    rect.y = 0;
    rect.w = 1280;
    rect.h = 720;

    SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, texture, NULL, &rect);

    SDL_Delay(2000);

    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);

    SDL_Quit();

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: [SDL_Init is a function](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_Init), you should have written `SDL_Init(/* flags go here */);` right now its not being called. Also I'm pretty sure you should call this *before* doing anything sdl related. Not sure if thats your problem or not but that is definitely odd.

Comment: You have a similar problem with SDL_Quit at the end, this is also a function, so youre missing parentheses again.

Comment: @Borgleader I fixed this and it didn't seem to solve my problem. Thanks for pointing it out though!

Comment: Also you should probably create the rederer after creating the window (which you dont seem to be assigning to your window variable...)

Comment: @Borgleader I fixed this too and it still isn't working. This is simply example code, most of these things are as they should be in my actual program. Again, thanks for pointing it out though.

Comment: Have you confirmed that the image was loaded properly? the only thing i can think of at this point is a relative path issue, so maybe try with an absolute path.

Comment: Where's your `SDL_RenderPresent()` call?  Why are you blocking the GUI thread for two seconds instead of using a proper event loop?

Comment: @genpfault Adding SDL_RenderPresent() fixed it, thanks! I used SDL_Delay() simply for example, my actual program is using an event loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working, I simply had to add `SDL_RenderPresent()`.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).